# How to pass parameters between cocos2d scenes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parameter-passing, scene

I am using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"SongLoadingScene.ccbi"] ]];
```

For transition scene by scene. How to pass parameters to a scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCBReader`'s `sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile` is just a class method that returns a new instance of `CCBReader`.

So, if you want to pass an integer to it, first modify `sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile` to receive it, like

```
+(CCScene*)sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:(NSString*)file andInteger:(int)integer;
```

And then modify `CCBReader`'s constructor to also receive it. If currently it looks like

```
-(id)initWithFile:(NSString*)file;
```

You'd have

```
-(id)initWithFile:(NSString*)file andInteger:(int)integer;
```

Finally you modify `sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile` to pass the integer to this new constructor.

Comment: Editing cocos2d itself? Not very practical.

Comment: @Jonny: You don't need to modify the currently implemented constructor. You can simply add another constructor method and keep the original right there.

Answer (score 2):

CCBReader returns a CCScene with whatever you pass as the only child, so you can create a constructor on you CustomScene like this:

```
@interface CustomScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) id customParameter;

@end

@implementation CustomScene

+ (CCScene *)sceneWithCustomParameter:(id)customParameter
{
    CCScene *customSceneParent = [CCBReader loadAsScene:NSStringFromClass([CustomScene class])];
    CustomScene *customScene = [customSceneParent.children firstObject];
    customScene.customParameter = customParameter;
    return customSceneParent;
}

@end
```

This should be applicable to any custom CCNode (e.g. CCSprite)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass parameters to a scene. However, you could try either of the following to overcome your problem.

1. Use another class, a singleton, and store the value of the parameter in a variable of the singleton. You could read that variable in your main scene.
2. Save the value in NSUserDefaults and read it in your scene.

Answer (score 1):

The secret lies in:

```
[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"YourCustomCCBFile"]
```

It creates a CCScene and adds your custom file as it's child.
If you want to access your custom object you can do this this way:

```
CCScene *scene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"YourCustomCCBFile"];
CustomClass *customObject = [[scene children] firstObject];
customObject.property = @"hi";

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
```

Just remember, that if you set some property this way, it will not be available in

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB
```

use instead:

```
- (void)onEnter
```